# How to most effectively check for newer versions and auto-update a Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script `install.py` on 20 different machines. I update this script and push it to `download.acme.com` after every tested change. Before we start a bigger rollout, what's the most effective way for a new version of this script to check if a newer version of itself exists? Also is scp the best way to distribute newer versions of software to people?

`\\ Check for newer version (ftp? ssh?)
download = input("Newer version available! Download? (y/n)")`

`if(download == 'y'):
   scp bob@download.acme.com:~/install.py ~/install.py`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python

Comment: If the script is on a remote machine is that the most effective way?

Comment: I'm experimenting with [devpi](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/) to solve this problem for my company. It sets up a pypi cache and then lets you add internal packages in a staged manner. You package your script via setup.py (increment the micro version number each time) and upload it to a development index. Risk tolerant users can configure pip to use this pypi index. When it works, it can be pushed to a stable index for others.